# UnsatisfiedLinkError OkHttpClient API 19

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp

I'm getting this error only on API 19:

```
Process: <myapp>, PID: 3378
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: (<clinit> failed, see exception in other thread)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:219)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:211)
```

Here:

```kotlin
val httpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
```

I think it has something to do with retrofit or okhttp, but a didn't find nothing about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't meet [the requirements](https://square.github.io/okhttp/#requirements).

> OkHttp works on Android 5.0+ (API level 21+) and on Java 8+.

You can downgrade to OkHttp 3.12.x or change your minimum API level to 21.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. He's right. Here is error log. when I use     implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2")

[image]